# transform dataframe to sf object using an already formated geometry column

Tags: r, dataframe, geometry, r-sf

I have a dataframe (dat) like this, geom_transect is a factor so far.
I would like to transform my dataframe to an sf object by specifying that geom_transect is a geometry column but without success.
here is my table

```
rn   geom_transect
1   c(2.59301435154815, 51.0850974058788)
2   c(2.65908408179987, 51.120810848601)
3   c(3.33344625797791, 51.3620269560137)
4   c(4.36158333330571, 51.2919925240015)
5   c(4.11514955241717, 51.1308060725143)
```

I tried:

```
st_as_sf(as.numeric(as.character(dat$geom_transect)))
```

i got the following error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("st_as_sf") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_as_sf' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
In addition: Warning message:
In st_as_sf(as.numeric(as.character(dat$geom_transect))) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

I also tried :

```
st_point(is.numeric(dat$geom_transect))

Error in st_point(is.numeric(dat$geom_transect)) : 
  is.numeric(x) is not TRUE
```

any help is welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot use `as.numeric` to convert "c(2.59301435154815, 51.0850974058788)" to two numbers. There's a missing step or three. You could try using `scan(text=.,sep=",", what="")`, or `eval(parse(text=.)`, or `strsplit(` followed by `sub()` to remove the "c(" and ")" and then `as.numeric`. I'm sure there are many duplicates of this question, although I admit the most effective method of searching is not immediately clear. After you make a search, possibly using some of the hints, you should edit you question to include `dput(head(dat))` and paste in the links of answers that were related.

Comment: You should also explain why the column looks like that. Did you make it that was under the mistaken assumption that there was an easy path forward to passing it to later functions? It mauy be much easier to backtrack to the point where you had raw text or raw numerics.

Answer (score 0):

you indeed put me on the track, thanks for that! I thought there would be an easier way and I do agree that I should have store the geometry table differently but the data extraction was long and I do not want to re-run that part of the code.

this is what I finally did to retrieve the lon/lat coordinates:

```
dat$geom_transect <- as.character(dat$geom_transect)
dat$lon <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(dat$geom_transect, '[(,)]'), "[[", 2))
dat$lat <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(dat$geom_transect, '[(,)]'), "[[", 3))
```